# How to get sql lite datas in andorid?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, insert

In this code I have to insert sqlite data's to SQL server.First I have to store all data's in sqlite database and then clicking a button the entire data should be inserted in SQL server.My problem is the first row only inserted in all rows.For example; if I inserted three different rows in Sqlite,but the three rows have same first row values in Sql server....
how to resolve.I'm using Move to first and Move to next also...but I can't get.
Guys I need your help

// Databse Coding

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static int dbversion=1;
    static String dbname="auction.db";
    String TABLE_CONTACTS = "auctions";
    public Database(Context context)
             {
        super(context, dbname, null, dbversion);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create table Auction(boname VARCHAR NOT NULL,bname VARCHAR NOT NULL, amount VARCHAR NOT NULL,daty DATE)");


}

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

// JAva coding

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Database db=new Database(MainActivity.this);
            SQLiteDatabase sb=db.getReadableDatabase();


            Cursor cus=sb.rawQuery("select * from Auction",null);
            cus.moveToFirst();


             for(int i=0;i<cus.getCount();i++)
             {


             String Boatnum= cus.getString(0).toString();
             String Buyername=cus.getString(1).toString();

             String amount=     cus.getString(2).toString();




                        request.addProperty("Boatnum",Boatnum);
                        request.addProperty("Buyername",Buyername);
                        request.addProperty("amount",amount);


                                    envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                                    envelope.dotNet=true;
                                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                                    httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);





                                    try {

                                         serviceCall();



                                    } 


                                    catch (Exception exception) {


                                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



              }
                                cus.moveToNext(); 


             }              


         }
```

Comment: Can you please post your database schema?

Comment: Give an id like this at the start of your table and check:

UID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,

Comment: if I give auto increment,it will show all data's ah..

Comment: If your query is right it will...

Comment: still having the same problem

Comment: What exactly is happening, problem is in db or server?

Comment: Problem is getting data's in Database.The problem is in my coding either the move to First nor Move to Next.The data's are displayed but it shows the same data...Getting the data's from the table is main problem

Comment: Are you fetching list of values or a single row? Can I know that. You can remove  cus.moveToNext();, moveToFirst should be sufficient.

Comment: Try to fetch list of values....

Answer (score 0):

Can you comment your present code and try the following one:

```
Cursor cus=sb.rawQuery("select * from Auction",null);
            if (cus != null) { 
            cus.moveToFirst();
    }
```

Comment every thing and only have these in your method and try and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....But the same problem occurs and using this code nothing happens in that method

Comment: Are you sure data in getting inserted?

Comment: no errors...but still save the same problem...Actually if I insert three datas in sqllite table,it will shows the reports Pakka..but insert using soap web service in sql server the three datas has displayed but all have same values which i insert in first row.

Comment: means there is no problem with db it is with your soap web service.